# Strictly segregate traffic in nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, performance, reverse-proxy

I have nginx configured as a reverse proxy.  It proxies two upstreams not under my control: Speedy and Flaky.

**Speedy** has consistently high uptime and consistently low response times.

**Flaky** sometimes has periods of downtime and relatively sluggish response times, with frequent periods where response times take 3 or more seconds.

The problem is that sometimes when Flaky's response times spike, it causes timeouts for Speedy.  I assume it's because all available connections are being clogged up waiting for Flaky's responses.  I've already tried a variety of strategies to mitigate, such as employing `max_fails` in Flaky's `upstream` configuration, but the problem persists.

My question is whether I can run two entirely separate instances of nginx on the same machine: one that only handles requests for Speedy and one that only handles requests for Flaky.

(And I guess the follow-up question is whether that is likely to solve the problem and ensure that Speedy is not affected by Flaky's flakiness.)

Answer (score 0):

I would put a limit on the resources that go to Flaky.  Have a look at limit_conn and limit_conn_zone.  Use the same variables that let you decide which backend receives the requests.